# How to detect if current window is behind another window, using Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

Is it possible to detect whether the web browser window is currently covered by another window?

document.hidden and document.visibilityState only changes state on switching tabs or when the entire window is minimized.

document.hasFocus() returns false if the window is visible but not in focus (e.g. the focus is on the taskbar)

Comment: if from same domain - with some trickery yes. if covered by window from different domain or even application - no

Comment: @Peter: Even then you still have no idea how large the toolbars are, or where on the screen the window is positioned.

Comment: @Cerbrus what about [window.screenX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/screenX) ?

Comment: @Kaiido: `-1920` on the left monitor of my 2-screen setup, for a fullscreen window. I'm sure you could figure out the exact position and screen, but there's still no way to see what portion of the page is actually rendered, considering overlapping windows.

Comment: not sure for browser support http://plnkr.co/edit/uF6sK5nX5M0IMhgaMQaR?p=preview

Comment: @Kaiido: You usually can't call `window.open` from plainJS. Has to be in a click (or other user-initiated) event. In chrome, that plnkr does nothing for me.

Comment: @Cerbrus, I had the *Always show popups from ..*  thing enabled. Also, you need to be in windowed mode (my code doesn't take account for iframe's inner position)

Answer (score 3):

Nope, that's not possible.

There's no way in JavaScript to know how visible the window is.

Comment: ... from web context. in chrome context (plugins) you have access to [more powerful APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows).

Comment: @Kaiido Can't see how you'd find out if the window is being overlapped with that API (only quickly skimmed it), also what about other browsers.

Comment: @George, the answer states *There's no way in JavaScript to know how visible the window is.*  The API I linked to provides informations such as [`WindowState`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#WindowState), `top`, `left`, `width`, `height`. So by iterating over all the windows, you can know if one of the **browser's** windows is over an other one. But yes of course it's still limited to the windows of this browser.

Answer (score 2):

Browser windows overlapping one another, the position of the browser windows, and which one of them is on top - these functionalities are handled by the operating system.

No matter what code you write for your webpage, you cannot tell if your browser window is overlapped by another.

So yeah, the answer is **NO**.

Comment: .. without providing any explanation.

Comment: What can I say? JS doesn't have access to anything that would help in that regard...

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since the OP, but for me the [Page Visiblity API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) does appear to allow you to event off of another application's window covering the browser window, at least in Firefox on Windows 11.

To test:

1. Open a window of window's File Explorer and change it so that it's smallish
2. Go to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API in Firefox
3. Set the browser window to be wider or taller than the File Explorer window
4. Play the demo sound on the MDN page
5. Alt-Tab over to the file explorer window. The sound does not stop.
6. Drag the edges one by one until the file explorer window covers the browser window. Note that the sound only stops playing when the browser window is completely covered.
7. Drag one of the edges of the file explorer window back so the browser isn't covered. The sound starts again.

Comment: Same behavior for `requestAnimationFrame`: This is suspended when the page is entirely covered by another window (tried it out with the snippet from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77972475/is-there-anyway-i-can-force-the-browser-to-update-its-ui-render-even-it-is-in/77972711#77972711)).

Comment: But this works only for whole windows, not for individual iframes: these are still animated even if wholly covered (as long as the window containing them remains at least partially visible).

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible if your website runs as one website.
By using Window Focus and Blur events.

Note: this is expecting that all code is executed in the same frame as the snippet below is executed in an iframe which behaves as if it was in a separate window!

```js
var element = document.getElementById("out");

window.onblur = () => {
  element.innerHTML = "I lost focus"
}
window.onfocus = () => {
  element.innerHTML = "Focus"
}
```

```html
<div id="out">Focus</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your information is incorrect.  You should use document.hidden in this scenario.  We tested this thoroughly in our own project and it is used to stop refreshing javascript from running on a map when the page is obscured from view, and it indeed instantly works simply by having the window behind another window.  Minimizing is not a requirement.
edit:  As per the comment by xdhmoore, there is also an event available.  The information is this:

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {
if (document.hidden) {
    dosomething();
  } else {
    dosomethingelse();
  }
});
```

The link is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API
but in case that link ever dies, a basic code sample is provided here.

Comment: Is this type of polling needed when the `visibilitychange` event exists? Both the `visibilitychange` event and `document.hidden` are mentioned on the [Page Visibility API MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API)

Comment: probably not.  I was not aware the event was available.  It's really just re-using code that was already on the page already to refresh a google map showing driver locations.   I suppose it could be rewritten to use events on page visibility instead.