# Is there anyway I can force the browser to update its UI (render) even it is in the background? (JavaScript?/CLI arguments?/config flags?)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, microsoft-edge, chromium

**Background**

Without going into details, I am writing a browser app site that should display real time metrics, but the browser is being captured by a Windows screen capturer, and sometimes the browser might go in the background.

I know there is some mechanic in modern browsers that halts/stops the browser to execute if the browser is in the background. I am not really sure what this is called, but I know it exists.

**Using Web Workers for updating data**

In order to by pass that `setInterval`/`setTimeout` stops if the browser is in the background, I am using [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API). This works great, as I can process all the data even if the browser is in the background.

**The problem**

The problem I am facing is that the UI does not get updated at all if the browser is in background.

I understand why because of performance reasons.

But I was hoping that a Web Worker's `postMessage/addEventListener("message")` would trigger an animation request, but it doesn't seem to do that.

**Question**

Does anyone know any way at all to update the UI even if the browser is in the background?

For example;

- Preferable with JavaScript APIs/tricks
- Browser command line arguments
- Browser config flags

Anything that would allow a browser in the background to UI update itself.

Comment: No, this is nothing a JavaScript API would be allowed to do. At best, you can try to display your web page as fullscreen.

Comment: This sounds like a bug of the screen capturing software. Try reporting this issue to them

Answer (score 2):

As you already stated, the browser pauses UI operations such as `requestAnimationFrame` while the UI is invisible. This is also demonstrated by the following snippet, which shows an ever increasing count of animation frames, but only while the UI is visible:

```js
var frames = 0;
function countFrames() {
  document.body.textContent = frames++;
  requestAnimationFrame(countFrames);
}
```

```html
<body onload="countFrames()"></body>
```

But you can use [puppeteer](/questions/tagged/puppeteer) (or [electron](/questions/tagged/electron)) to run the browser entirely in the background, including all UI operations. This is demonstrated by the following Node.js program (which assumes that the snippet above is available at C:/snippet.html):

```js
async function countFrames() {
  console.log(await body.evaluate(e => e.textContent));
  setTimeout(countFrames, 1000);
}
var browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: "new" });
var page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto("C:/snippet.html"), { waitUntil: "networkidle2" })
var body = await page.$("body");
countFrames();
```

This regularly logs the increasing animation frame count, although no browser UI is visible.

Instead of logging a string value, you would call puppeteer's [screenshot](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.screenshot) function to take screenshots at regular intervals.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah cool, I assume that Puppeteer is kinda like Electron. Good to know.